# Conditional group by with window function in Snowflake query

Tags: sql, window-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, row-number

I have a table in Snowflake in following format:

```
create temp_test(name string, split string, value int)

insert into temp_test
values ('A','a', 100), ('A','b', 200), ('A','c',300), ('A', 'd', 400), ('A', 'e',500), ('B', 'a', 1000), ('B','b', 2000), ('B','c', 3000), ('B', 'd',4000), ('B','e', 5000)
```

First step, I needed only **top 2 value per name** (sorted on value), so I used following query to get that:

```
select name, split, value,
row_number() over (PARTITION BY (name) order by value desc) as row_num 
from temp_test
qualify row_num <= 2
```

Which gives me following resultset:

```
NAME    SPLIT   VALUE   ROW_NUM
A       e       500     1
A       d       400     2
B       e       5000    1
B       d       4000    2
```

Now, I need to sum values other than Top 2 and put it in a different Split named as "Others", like this:

```
NAME    SPLIT   VALUE   
A       e       500     
A       d       400     
A       Others  600        
B       e       5000    
B       d       4000
B       Others  6000
```

How to do that in Snowflake query or SQL in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select name, split, value,
        row_number() over (partition by (name) order by value desc) as row_num 
    from temp_test
)
select
    name,
    case when row_num <= 2 then split else 'Others' end as split,
    sum(value) as value
from data
group by name, case when row_num <= 2 then row_num else 3 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Shawnt00's answer is good, but for the record in Snowflake this can be written simpler:

Firstly the group by at the end can refer to the results by index or name:

```
GROUP BY 1,2
```

or

```
GROUP BY name, split
```

also as the CASE only has too branches an IFF can be used and seems you are using a CTE to add the row_number you can push the IFF into the CTE also

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT name, value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY value DESC) AS row_num,
        IFF(row_num < 3, split, 'Others') as n_split
    FROM VALUES ('A','a', 100), ('A','b', 200), ('A','c',300), ('A', 'd', 400), 
                ('A', 'e',500), ('B', 'a', 1000), ('B','b', 2000), ('B','c', 3000), 
                ('B', 'd',4000), ('B','e', 5000) 
    v(name, split, value)
)   
SELECT
    name,
    n_split,
    SUM(value) AS value
FROM data
GROUP BY name, n_split;
```

and if super keen on small SQL push the ROW_NUMBER into the IFF:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT name, value,
        IFF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY value DESC) < 3, split, 'Others') as n_split
    FROM VALUES ('A','a', 100), ('A','b', 200), ('A','c',300), ('A', 'd', 400), 
                ('A', 'e',500), ('B', 'a', 1000), ('B','b', 2000), ('B','c', 3000), 
                ('B', 'd',4000), ('B','e', 5000) 
    v(name, split, value)
)   
SELECT
    name,
    n_split AS split,
    SUM(value) AS value
FROM data
GROUP BY name, n_split;
```

gives:

```
NAME    SPLIT   VALUE
A       e       500
A       d       400
A       Others  600
B       e       5000
B       d       4000
B       Others  6000
```